# CSS: Making a DIV full screen width height without change the proportion of the absolute divs inside

Tags: html, css, height, width

I have create a mobile site template (320x640) size and the problem is that the background is a picture and the input boxes is absolute position (related to the background picture). I want to make it 100% width and 100% height but then the absolute input positions wouldn't be related to the picture anymore.

I want to know if there is a quick css fix so the full screen of the user would be 320x640 (y scroll is ok) but 320px width is 100% of any user that will access the page.

Here is the jsfiddle demo :

http://jsfiddle.net/t7mcn0me/

html :

```
<div id=mobile>
    <input style="position:absolute;top:10px;left:10px;">

</div>
```

css:

```
#mobile
{
    background:url('http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-oRxMu07qqUk/TqiWzl3hAaI/AAAAAAAACWc/EB6lFVu2PQI/s1600/greenlake__%252528www.mobile16.net%252529.jpg');
    margin:0 auto;
    width:320px;
    height:640px;
    position: relative;
    border:1px solid grey;
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: I am not quite sure if I follow, But I believe what you want here, is Width set to 100%, and your height to auto :)

Answer (score 0):

try this
http://jsfiddle.net/t7mcn0me/2/

html

```
<div id=mobile>
<input style=" position:absolute;top:10px; width: 100vw!important;">
```

css

```
 #mobile
{
    background:url('http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-oRxMu07qqUk/TqiWzl3hAaI/AAAAAAAACWc/EB6lFVu2PQI/s1600/greenlake__%252528www.mobile16.net%252529.jpg');
    margin:0 auto;
    width:320px;
    width: 100vw!important;
    height:640px;
    position: relative;
    border:1px solid grey;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;
}
```